# htaccess non-www to www only redirects to index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The following is only redirecting to the index. It doesn't preserve urls. e.g. `www.mysite.com/anotherpage` redirects to `mysite.com/index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Full htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Move this `www` rule just below `RewriteEngine` and clear cache

Comment: Thanks a ton. Did the trick